# 3-D plot of spikes in graph matlab

Tags: matlab

What would be the best way to get an image similar to the one below.
Here is my data set.

```
xx = [50 93 32];
yy = [93 63 42];
zz = [0.443 0.743 0.302];
```

Where `xx` is Elevation(theta), `yy` is Azimuth(phi), and `zz` is HSH-MVDR. I have been doing `contour3` and `surf` command but keep getting the error: "Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector." Points that are not in the dataset I want to be 0 for cordinates `zz`, so I am expecting only 3 points to have spikes.

[image]

Comment: You have 3 points. you want to plot an entire surface? You just have not enough information. You can always make a mesgrid, make `z` all zero and in 3 locations add a value I guess.

Comment: Yes, I want `z` to be all zeros except for where it matches up with `xx` and `yy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make a meshgrid (making sure your x,y indices are included)

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(0:100,0:400);
```

create `z`

```
z=zeros(size(x));
```

and fill it

```
z(sub2ind(size(z),xx,yy))=zz;
```

then plot

```
surf(x,y,z) % surf(x,y,z,'linestyle','none');shading interp; ?
```